# Trying to install gatsby-cli getting error

Tags: ubuntu, npm, gatsby

When I try to install gatsby, it is successfully installed but gives an error during gatsby-cli which is mentioned below.

[image: error picture]

---

```
[Container] 2020/06/24 17:33:22 Running command npm install -g gatsby-cli

npm WARN deprecated core-js@2.6.11: core-js@<3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js@3.

npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated

npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated

npm WARN acorn-dynamic-import@4.0.0 requires a peer of acorn@^6.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

npm ERR! code EEXIST

npm ERR! syscall symlink

npm ERR! path ../lib/node_modules/gatsby-cli/cli.js

npm ERR! dest /usr/local/bin/gatsby

npm ERR! errno -17

npm ERR! EEXIST: file already exists, symlink '../lib/node_modules/gatsby-cli/cli.js' -> '/usr/local/bin/gatsby'

npm ERR! File exists: /usr/local/bin/gatsby

npm ERR! Remove the existing file and try again, or run npm

npm ERR! with --force to overwrite files recklessly.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:

npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2020-06-24T17_33_41_230Z-debug.log

[Container] 2020/06/24 17:33:41 Command did not exit successfully npm install -g gatsby-cli exit status 239

[Container] 2020/06/24 17:33:41 Phase complete: INSTALL State: FAILED

[Container] 2020/06/24 17:33:41 Phase context status code: COMMAND_EXECUTION_ERROR Message:
 
Error while executing command: npm install -g gatsby-cli. Reason: exit status 239
```

Comment: Looks like it fails for the reason the package already exists. Try to uninstall it, then reinstall it: 
`npm uninstall -g gatsby-cli` , then: `npm install -g gatsby-cli`.
Let me know it helped. If it does, I'll write it as an answer :)

Comment: I try uninstall but error not remove(same error)

Comment: Its show gatsby-cli already exist so i resolve by installing only {npm i -g gatsby} and its work now(leaving again installation of gatsby-cli)

Comment: So installing gatsby alone fixed it?

Comment: Yes its solve the problem

Comment: @Dani Using `npm i -g gatsby` doesn't work for me. It shows another set of errors.